# php number_format not using locale

Tags: php

It's a first for me, using setLocale, I usually hate using it because I work on shared hosting, but since changing job recently, I have gained server control and thus the ability to install locales.

When I switch to fr_CA on my application, I call

```
money_format('%n', $value)
```

And it formats the currency correctly, but strangely, if I

```
number_format($value, 2);
```

I get a number formatted with the correct amount of decimals (2) but the decimal separator is not what was expected. I'm getting "0.32" instead of "0,32" like the locale says.

I even checked the locale on the server, and it clearly shows that the decimal separator is a comma:

```
LC_NUMERIC
decimal_point             "<U002C>"
thousands_sep             "<U0020>"
grouping                  3;3
END LC_NUMERIC
```

I checked online and U002C is indead comma... not period...

What's your take on this?

PS, here's what i checked:

1. setLocale does return fr_CA
2. setLocale clearly formats correctly and my code is not overriding the symbols in the call to number_format

Thanks

Comment: number_format() isn't locale aware; it's up to you to specify the decimal and thousands separators as arguments to the function

Comment: O_O ok, i'm blushing now, i thought it would use it. So whats the real PHP based alternative... a readable one...

Comment: The alternative is to use [localeconv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php) to retrieve that information and use it in number_format(), something like: `$locale = localeconv(); echo number_format($number, $locale['frac_digits'], $locale['decimal_point'], $locale['thousands_sep']);`

Comment: @MarkBaker This is a little silly don't you think? I'll see what i can do, maybe i'll provide my first ever patch to PHP :) Get an anwser out so i can give you your points

Comment: Personally I wish they'd locale-ise DateTime objects as well (the equivalent of strftime()), but it would certainly be useful if number_format() was locale-aware.... as money_format() already is locale-aware, it would be a logical step, and should be fairly straightforward to identify how it's been done for money_format(), and apply the same logic to number_format()

Comment: If you do a patch, don't get too disheartened by the negativism of the PHP core developers: bribery, blackmail, threats, etc. can be useful techniques to fight it through to acceptance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative is to use [localeconv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php) to retrieve that information and use it in number_format(), something like:

```
$locale = localeconv(); 
echo number_format(
    $number, 
    $locale['frac_digits'], 
    $locale['decimal_point'], 
    $locale['thousands_sep']
);
```